# SQL Select, replace ID with table column from foreign key

Tags: mysql, select

Lets say I have two tables, and in this example, the fish table has Place as a foreign key. In a select statement, how can I get the average weight per place, but instead of showing the id, it shows either the name of the place or the country that has the same id.

```
Fish
ID Type   Weigth Place
1  Cod    300    1
2  Pike   600    2
3  Pike   1000   2
4  Salmon 800    1

Place
ID Name   Country
1  NY     USA
2  London UK
3  Oslo   Norway
```

I can only figure out how to get average weight per place and return the id, but not the name or country of the place. I think I need to use join of some sort, but cant figure out how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Join tables using proper joining condition...

Comment: Search for group by multiple tables.